# Using Swift RegexBuilder in a lexer - collapsing ChoiceOf match output tuple to (SubString, TypeOfMatch) type

Tags: swift, tokenize, lexer, swift-regexbuilder

I'm implementing a parser using Swift's `RegexBuilder` for the lexer stage. I would like to understand if my regex `ChoiceOf` statement could be improved.

Specifically in the example code below, when `tokenRegex` matches it produces a tuple of type `(SubString, Token?, Token?, ...)`, where the number of `Token?` members will be equal to the number regex terms in the `ChoiceOf` construct. Assuming all the regex terms in the `ChoiceOf` block return type `Token`, is there anyway to express it so that the return type is `(SubString, Token?)`.

At present I deal with this by collapsing the match output tuple using the mirror functionality, but would like to skip this step if possible:

```swift
let token = Mirror(reflecting: match.output).children.compactMap({ $0.value as? Token }).first
```

Here's the full example code.

```swift
import Foundation
import RegexBuilder

enum Token {
    case number(Double)
    case text(String)
    case error(String)
    
    static let tokenRegex = Regex {
        ChoiceOf {
            numberRegex
            textRegex
            // Further regex patterns, all returning type Token...
        }
    }
    
    static let numberRegex = Regex {
        Capture {
            .localizedDouble(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
        } transform: {
            Token.number($0)
    }}
    
    static let textRegex = Regex {
        Capture {
            OneOrMore(.word)
        } transform: {
            Token.text(String($0))
    }}
    
    static func tokenise(_ text: String) -> [Token] {
        var stringToParse = text
        var tokens: [Token] = []
        
        while !stringToParse.isEmpty {
            let (token, matchEndIndex) = findNextToken(in: stringToParse)
            tokens.append(token)
            stringToParse = String(stringToParse[matchEndIndex...])
        }
        return tokens
    }
    
    static func findNextToken(in string: String) -> (Token, String.Index) {
        do {
            return if
                let match = try tokenRegex.firstMatch(in: string),
                let token = Mirror(reflecting: match.output).children.compactMap({ $0.value as? Token }).first
            {
                (token, match.0.endIndex)
            } else {
                (.error("Parse error"), string.endIndex)
            }
        } catch {
            return (.error(error.localizedDescription), string.endIndex)
        }
    }
}

Token.tokenise("123MyDogIsHappy") // Produces -> [Token.double(123.0), Token.text("MyDogIsHappy")]
```